# Load CSV by matching table column to SQL using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, csv

My requirement is to load system generated CSV file into an SQL table. Below I'm providing the CSV file, table query and my code.

Below are the CSV files `abc.csv` and `xyz.csv` which column comes changing by column every time like in the second file as you can see last two column shuffled.

```
id,Name,name,Shift,Day,Night
1,ert,sdf,08/21/2017 Day,2,-
2,wer,asdf,08/21/2017 Day,-,1
3,rty,adsf,08/21/2017 Day,1,-
4,yui,adsf,08/21/2017 Day,-,-
5,qwe,asdf,08/21/2017 Day,-,-
6,ret,asdf,08/21/2017 Day,-,-
7,chh,asdf,08/21/2017 Day,-,-
8,sdf,cxvv,08/21/2017 Day,1,-
```

```
id,Name,name,Shift,Night,Day
1,ert,sdf,08/21/2017 Day,-,2
2,wer,asdf,08/21/2017 Day,1,-
3,rty,adsf,08/21/2017 Day,-,1
4,yui,adsf,08/21/2017 Day,-,-
5,qwe,asdf,08/21/2017 Day,-,-
6,ret,asdf,08/21/2017 Day,-,-
7,chh,asdf,08/21/2017 Day,-,-
8,sdf,cxvv,08/21/2017 Day,-,1
```

Below is the create table query to load this data in SQL:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE MES;
USE MES;
CREATE TABLE MESdata
(
    Id              int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Employee_id     int NOT NULL,
    First_Name      varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Last_Name       varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Shift           varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Day             int NULL,
    Night           int NULL
);
```

Below is my attempt in PowerShell using `Out-datatable.ps1` and `write-datatable.ps1`:

```bsh
. C:\ReadCSV\Out-datatable.ps1;
. C:\ReadCSV\write-datatable.ps1;

if (Test-Path Variable:\my_import) {
    Remove-Variable my_import
}

$csvfile    = 'C:\ReadCSV\abc.csv'
$header     = Get-Content 'C:\ReadCSV\abc.csv' | select -First 1
$sqlTable   = 'MESdata'
$DataSource = 'HOST\INSTANCE'
$DataBase   = 'MES'
$my_import  = Import-Csv -UseCulture -Header $header $csvfile |
              select @{Label="Employee_id";Expression={$_."id"}},
                     @{Label="First_Name";Expression={$_."Name"}},
                     @{Label="Last_Name";Expression={$_."name"}},
                     @{Label="Shift";Expression={$_."Shift"}},
                     @{Label="Day";Expression={$_."Day"}},
                     @{Label="Night";Expression={$_."Night"}} |
              Out-DataTable    
Write-DataTable -ServerInstance $DataSource -Database $DataBase -TableName $sqlTable -Data $my_import
#$ConnectionString ='Data Source={0}; Database={1}; Trusted_Connection=True;' -f $DataSource,$DataBase
#$bulkCopy = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($ConnectionString)
#$bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = $sqlTable
#$bulkCopy.WriteToServer($my_import)
```

I got this first error:

```
Exception calling "WriteToServer" with "1" argument(s): "Column 'Employee_id'
does not allow DBNull.Value."
At C:\ReadCSV\stackoverflow.ps1:25 char:1
+ $bulkCopy.WriteToServer($my_import)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
```

What should I do? Do I need to change the datatype of table fields but I don't want like that. But if I replace all not null to null then the script executed without error but with all NULL data.

Comment: You don't need to do this `-Header $header` and I suspect its causing your issue.

Comment: That being said I think you'll have an issue having two columns named "Name" as PowerShell is not case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a well formed CSV file you don't need to manually specify the `-Header` line, PowerShell will figure this out automatically. However your file has a duplicate column name (PowerShell is case sensitive so `Name` is duplicate of `name`) and you will get an error like:

```
The member "Name" is already present
```

To work around this you'll either need to rename one of these columns first to make them unique (and then drop the `-Header` part of your code), or alternatively you could use the `-Header` property to manually specify the full header line using whatever property names you want for each column. You do this using an array of strings e.g:

```
$my_import = Import-CSV –useCulture -Header 'Employee_id','First_Name','Last_Name','Shift','Day','Night' $csvfile | Out-datatable
```

By doing this you also then do not need to do the `Select` part of your code to rename the column names, as they will be set correctly to start with.

Comment: Renaming the duplicate header is arguably the better option, since it doesn't require knowledge about the order of the columns.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I changed my script as you mentioned about headers but my main problem is my input CSV file get change every time with column placement as I shown in xyz.csv so I wanted the correct data goes inside the correct field of table that's why I use 'select' but now I'm getting he given value of type String from the data 
source cannot be converted to type int of the specified target column." this error data is not going to sql table. Please help me with the code

Comment: @Paddy `Import-Csv` does that automatically, provided your CSV file has a header line and there are no duplicate column names.